# How to import data from excel into R as time series

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, dplyr, time-series

I have this excel data sheet that I want to import into R as a time series object. However, i am not sure of how to go about it.

[image]

How would i import this data into R?

Comment: 2 steps: use `read_xlsx` from `openxlsx` and then transform from wide to long.

Comment: how do i transform from wide to long?

Answer (score 1):

first you cam use the `openxlsx` package to read the data:

```
library(openxlsx)
mydata <- read.xlsx("path to your xlsx")
```

Afterwards you can use the `tidyverse` package to transform your data to a `ts` object:

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata %>%
  mutate(Month = 1:n()) %>% 
  gather(Year, value, -Month) %>% 
  arrange(Year, Month) %>%
  {ts(.$value, start = c(2013, 1), frequency = 12)}
```

Comment: An alternative:
mydata <-  readxl:: read_excel("path before this\crimedata.xlsx",sheet="month")